# jgit tag -f doesn't seem to work

Tags: jgit

I am trying to move a tag on a remote Git repo. With the git command-line, I can do something like this:

```
git tag -f <someTag>
git push --tags
```

But when using JGit, I need to set the force flag on both the tag and the push commands.

```java
git.tag().setName(lastSyncTag).setForceUpdate(true).call();
git.push().setPushTags().setForce(true) // WHY is this needed?
    .setRemote(gitUrl).setCredentialsProvider(credentials).call();
```

If I remove the `setForce(true)` from the push, the tag is not moved in the remote repository. However, the first time I create the tag, it is properly pushed to the remote repository.

Just wondering if I'm missing something. Any thoughts?

Comment: Forgot to mention. I'm using version 3.6.2.201501210735-r.

Comment: I can tag and push in JGit without using `setForce(Update)`. Are you sure that the tag that you are about to create does not yet exist (i.e. `git.tagList().call().contains( lastSyncTag ) == false`)? I can share code of a working example if that would help.

Comment: Thanks Rüdiger. When the tag is not in the server, I can tag without `setForceUpdate()` and push without `setForce()`, and it works. 

However, when the tag is in the server, and I want to move it from an old commit to a new one, I need to tag with `setForceUpdate()` and push with `setForce()`. In git command line, only the tag command needs the force flag. I would like to avoid the `setForce()` on the push because that could have other side-effects, especially in a larger push.

Comment: I ran `git.tagList().call()` and it returned a list of Ref objects with the correct tags on the server. I could match the lastSyncTag using the condition `ref.getName().equals("refs/tags/" + lastSyncTag)`.

Comment: If there is a difference in when _force_ is to be used between Git and JGit, then you could [file a bug against JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/support/) so that this gets fixed.

Comment: Thanks again. Filed a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=458753